# How to access method in controller from another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can i access a method in tableController from my menuController. Here is my code.i want to call addRow() method from select() in menu controller. these controllers are in different modules.Please Help me.

```
     my menu controller
     var menuApp = angular.module('menuApp', []);
menuApp.controller('menuController', ['tableService', function ($scope, tableService) {
    $scope.menuItem = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "new",
            navigate:"N",
            child: [{
                id: 11,
                title: "new11",
                navigate: "N",
                child: [{
                    id: 12,
                    title: "new12",
                    navigate: "Y",
                    url:"/Home/index"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "new",
            child: [{
                id: 21,
                title: "new21",
                child: [{
                    id: 22,
                    title: "new22"
                }]
            }]
        }
    ];

    $scope.select = function (data) {
        if (data.navigate == "Y") {
            alert(data.url);
            tableService.add();
        }
    }
}]);
```

my table controller

```
     tableApp.controller('tableController', function ($scope, $rootScope,      $filter, $uibModal) {
    $scope.filteredPeople = [];

    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.people = [{ id: "1", name: "joe",disable:true },
                 { id: "2", name: "bill", disable: true },
                 { id: "3", name: "john", disable: true },
    { id: "1", name: "joe", disable: true },
                 { id: "2", name: "bill", disable: true },
                 { id: "3", name: "john", disable: true },
    { id: "1", name: "joe", disable: true },
                 { id: "2", name: "bill", disable: true },
                 { id: "3", name: "john", disable: true },
    { id: "1", name: "joe", disable: true },
                 { id: "2", name: "bill", disable: true },
                 { id: "3", name: "john", disable: true },
    { id: "1", name: "joe", disable: true },
                 { id: "2", name: "bill", disable: true },
                 { id: "3", name: "john", disable: true }];

    $scope.addRow = function () {
        debugger;
        $scope.people.unshift({
            id: "",
            name: "",
            disable:false
        });
        $scope.getPage();
    }

    $scope.getPage = function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.pageSize);
        var end = begin + $scope.pageSize;
        $scope.filteredPeople = $filter('filter')($scope.people, {
            id: $scope.idFilter,
            name: $scope.nameFilter

        });
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.filteredPeople.length;
        $scope.filteredPeople = $scope.filteredPeople.slice(begin, end);
    };
    $scope.getPage();

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        $scope.getPage();
    };
    $scope.open = function () {
        $scope.id = generateUUID();
    };
    $scope.dblclick = function (index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredPeople.length; i++) {
            $scope.filteredPeople[i].disable = true;
        }
        return index.disable = false;
    }
    $scope.rowSelect = function (rowdata) {
        alert(rowdata.name);
    }
    $scope.openInput = function (index) {
        debugger;
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Home/index',
            controller: 'testController',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return index;
                },
                cat: function () {
                    return 'Account';
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I think you can create a service with the fonctions you want to share between controllers & directives

Comment: @Alainlb i created a service named tableService. but that was not work for  me. can u paste a example here?

Comment: It is not a good practice to call controller methods inside other controller. Like @Alainlb suggested is better if you create a separate service that you can inject in other components. This way your code is DRY, more modular and more flexible.

Comment: @Mirceac Thank you, How can i do it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a service shared between controllers & directives

```
/**
 * store and share data between controllers & directives
 */
angular.module('interfaceApp').service('shareData', function () {
    this.datas = [];

    this.add = function (data) {
        this.datas.push(data);
    };

    //retourne l'élément correspondant à la clé ( utilise la date comme clé )
    this.getElement = function (key) {
        ......
        return ;
    };

    this.getDatas = function () {
        return this.datas;
    };

});


/* Controller */
var searchModule = angular.module('searchModule', []);
   // inject the service in the controller
.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, shareData ) {

        shareData.add( ... );

        console.log( shareData.getDatas() );

});
```

A service is a singleton, so all controllers using it acces to the same datas ( when they call shareData.getDatas() )

Comment: Alainlb , but i want to access method in another controller. i dnt want to get data , i am trying to push data.

Comment: shareData.add( ... );

Comment: @Alainlb Thank you. its work for me. but its works only when when i add var app =angular.module('interfaceApp',[]);
app.service('shareData', function () { this.datas = []; ...................................... – Ajith 6 mins ago    
add a comment